# Using python can sockets on embedded linux, bind misbehaves

Tags: python, can-bus

I'm trying to interface to CAN drivers using python 3.4 running on embedded linux.
Theoretically there's a nice socketcan library available from python 3.3
but import can fails.

root@unit-901-100-sn003:~/francis# python3 
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 21:23:51) 
    import can
ImportError: No module named 'can'

Back to basics. Actually I was working on this before somebody pointed out 
    #!/usr/bin/env python3

```
import socket;

can_device = "can0";

sock_instance = socket.socket(socket.PF_CAN, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.CAN_RAW);
can_index = socket.if_nametoindex(can_device);
addr = (socket.AF_CAN, can_index); 
sock_instance.bind(addr);
```

root@unit-901-100-sn003:~/francis# ./sockio.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sockio.py", line 10, in 
    sock_instance.bind((can_device, can_index));
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

This program fails as above.
I'm obviously passing a single argument tuple or I've gone inanse?

If I just created a simple socket

```
si = socket.socket();
si.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000));
```

It executes so bind can recongise a tuple.

Comment: that traceback doesnt seem to match the code you have shown us ...

Comment: also to be able to `import can` you probably need to `pip install pycan` or something along those lines...

Comment: Sorry about that, I cut the file down, removed debug prints etc, and din't check the trace matched the source. Rude and careless I know!

I've since had a bit more success, it seems that bind was expecting a logical name as a string and performs its own if_nametoindex()

    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import socket;

    can_device = "can0";
    sock_instance = socket.socket(socket.PF_CAN, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.CAN_RAW);
    addr = (can_device,);
    sock_instance.bind(addr);

This doesn't raise an exception, so I'll continue and see if it becomes more useful.

Comment: @FrancisCagney have you already tried [python-can](https://python-can.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) project? It supports both Python 2 and 3 as also Windows.

Comment: I've actually had quite a bit of sucess with the can4python library. I can now send, but what I receive is garbled. Actually I'm using canframe.CanFrame() to create what I send, and what it sends seems garbled, but is received correctly the can monitor. Just have to work out how to use CanFrame to ungarble what is received.

Answer (score 1):

The python-can library actually has a [ctypes](https://bitbucket.org/hardbyte/python-can/src/10249b6e554466bae6f47df9f930c9f593f45002/can/interfaces/socketcan_ctypes.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and [native](https://bitbucket.org/hardbyte/python-can/src/10249b6e554466bae6f47df9f930c9f593f45002/can/interfaces/socketcan_native.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) python implementation that calls socketcan.

The binding is something like this:

```
channel = "can0"
sock = socket.socket(socket.PF_CAN, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.CAN_RAW)
sock.bind((channel,))
```